# Contact Form: Unable to send phone number

Tags: php, sendmail

I got this script online and it seems to work. However, the form doesn't seem to process name, phone1, phone2.

I don't see any process method where name, phone1, phone2 is being processed and send either.

Could someone help to get the name, phone1 and phone2 to be sent as well in the mail?

The form code has the correct fields and Chrome `console` shows that data is sent. What do you think is missing?

Here's the PHP script:

```
$recipient_email    = "myemail@gmail.com"; //recepient
$from_email         = "myemail@gmail.com"; //from email using site domain.

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die('Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'); //exit script
}

if($_POST){

    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender name
    $sender_email   = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture sender email
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["phone1"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //capture message

    $attachments = $_FILES['file_attach'];


    //php validation
    if(strlen($sender_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        exit;
    }
    if(!filter_var($sender_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        exit;
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        exit;
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        exit;
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        exit;
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        exit;
    }


    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5("sanwebe.com"); 

    if($file_count > 0){ //if attachment exists
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //message text
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

        //attachments
        for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){       
            if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

                if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                {
                    $mymsg = array( 
                    1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
                    2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
                    3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                    4=>"No file was uploaded", 
                    6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 
                    print  json_encode( array('type'=>'error',$mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]) ); 
                    exit;
                }

                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

                //read file 
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
                $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                $body .= $encoded_content; 
            }
        }

    }else{ //send plain email otherwise
       $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
        "Reply-To: ".$sender_email. "\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = $message;
    }

    $sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {       
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'done', 'text' => 'Thank you for your email'));
        exit;
    }else{
        print json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));  
        exit;
    }
}
```

PS: The developer who wrote this open-source script isn't responding.

Comment: You haven't add phone number in your $body

Comment: where you want the phone number in a message or in a subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right, apparently the author is not sending those fields. If you want them to appear in your email body, you can just concatenate them in the $body variable just before the line where the email is sent...

```
$body = "Name: " . $sender_name . "\r\n" .
        "Phone: (" . $country_code . ") " . $phone_number . "\r\n" .
        $body;

$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You just want to add phone number to message? If yes, I think below code is enough:

```
$body = $body . "\r\nPhone: " . $country_code . "-" . $phone_number;
$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

If line-breaker didn't work, try:

```
$body = $body . "

Phone: ". $country_code . "-" . $phone_number;

$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```